# I want something like the switch statement (but different of course)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a C# construct like the `switch` statement that allows control to fall through the next level?  I have something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SeverityOrHigher(string severity)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        switch (severity.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ALL":
                result.Add("ALL");
            case "DEBUG":
                result.Add("DEBUG");
            case "INFO":
                result.Add("INFO");
            case "WARN":
                result.Add("WARN");
            case "ERROR":
                result.Add("ERROR");
            case "FATAL":
                result.Add("FATAL");
            case "OFF":
                result.Add("OFF");
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

...which clearly does not work in C#, (`Control cannot fall through from one case label...`) yet it seems to me like it should.  I know it expects breaks in there, but that would not give me the data flow I'm looking for.  What can be done to make this happen the way I'd like?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You *could* use `goto case "DEBUG"` etc, but then you're using `goto` so Dijkstra will hate you.

Comment: Looks like an enum would better serve your root requirement here.

Comment: check out my edited answer for switch with go might work for you ....

Comment: @ChrisF, I would hope it would be clear what I am trying to achieve.  Given a specific Severity level, I want an enumerable list of that Severity level and all severities higher than it.

Comment: Well it *is* clear now you've explained it.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should use `ToUpperInvariant()`, or your code [won't work in Turkey](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case you can emulate "falling case" with a little bit of LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SeverityOrHigher(string severity)
{
    var result = new List<string>() 
        { "ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL", "OFF" };
    return result.SkipWhile(l => l != severity.ToUpper()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This looks... interesting.  Still not the C# language construct I was hoping for, but it seems cleaner than goto statements in a switch clause.

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit "clever" but I think it's still more readable than using `goto case`.

Comment: Readable... meh.  I would say the `goto case` is more readable.  But I don't like the idea of typing the word `goto` into a project anywhere.  Call me old-fashioned.

Comment: "But I don't like the idea of typing the word goto into a project anywhere. Call me old-fashioned" << Gotos are very old-school.  I shall call you new fashioned instead.

Answer (score 2):

Along with gotos, etc, you could do with this an enum and a bit of linq:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Severity> SeverityOrHigher(Severity severity)
    {
        var value = (int) severity;

        return Enum.GetValues(typeof (Severity))
            .Cast<int>()
            .Where(i => i >= value)
            .Select(i => (Severity) i);
    }

    public enum Severity
    {
        All = 0,
        Trace = 1,
        Debug = 2,
        Information = 3,
        Warning = 4,
        Error = 5,
        Fatal = 6
    }
```

Comment: I thought about doing this... unfortunately it implied parsing my log severity (which is a string via log4net) with every entry and I shied away from that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the optimal solution but you could use the `goto` statement like this:

```
switch (severity.ToUpper())
{
  case "ALL":
    result.Add("ALL");
    goto case "DEBUG";
  case "DEBUG":
    result.Add("DEBUG");
    goto case "INFO";
  case "INFO":
    result.Add("INFO");
    goto case "WARN";
  case "WARN":
    result.Add("WARN");
    goto case "ERROR";
  case "ERROR":
    result.Add("ERROR");
    goto case "FATAL";
  case "FATAL":
    result.Add("FATAL");
    goto case "OFF";
  case "OFF":
    result.Add("OFF");
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: This... doesn't look right.  I don't think this will achieve the proper result.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but also yes, this is not optimal.  I can't believe MS went with GOTO statements instead of letting control fall through labels.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Believe it.  Fall-through causes more bugs than it prevents.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe it.  If you write a crappy program, you get crappy results.  It's not the language's fault.  That's where disciplined testing regimens come into play.  If there's one thing I can't stand it's being protected from myself.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: Of course if you write a crappy program you get crappy results. That's a tautology. And of course it's not the language's fault. That's a straw man. Rather, the claim is that some languages are more conducive to bugs than others. For example, it is **clearly** true that programs written in C are more prone to memory leaks than programs written in C#. Just curious, do you not wear a seat belt or use ABS?

Comment: @Jason: I think this is far off topic, but I dislike the government protecting me from myself as well; a language is meant to maximize utility by providing flexibility.  To restrict something because it *might* screw you up is ridiculous; but if they were dead-set for it, an explicitly declared `continue`  / `yield` keyword or something along those lines to enable potentially dangerous code would be appropriate.  It would have been an elegant, easily readable solution to what I wanted to do, and it does work in many languages for expressly that reason.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: To restrict something because it might screw you up is not ridiculous. If you don't want a language that has safety features built in, then use a different language. But, you should avoid almost every high-level language existence. I'm not sure where you come up with a "language is meant to maximize utility by providing flexibility." I do not think you can apply such a broad statement to every programming language. But, more importantly, that clearly contradicts the [philosophy behind C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/08/14/c-and-the-pit-of-despair.aspx).

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: For example: "designing the language so as to prevent certain categories of subtle bugs is a huge priority for us." That is in direct opposition to your philosophy on languages. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, use a different language.

Comment: @Jason ... and what bug issues would arise from explicit fallthrough commands?  For most situations, C# is an excellent language to develop in; I feel that this is a particular limitation that should be mitigated, however.  I respect your opinion, but I firmly disagree with it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs explicit fallthrough commands will cause bugs if `case`s are carelessly reordered. With the goto approach, changing the order of the `case`s does not change the meaning of the program.

Comment: @phoog, that is the same thing as running commands in the wrong order.  There is a reasonable expectation that if you update code, you should update it correctly.  I doubt reordering cases was a consideration against implementation... but I could be wrong.  If I was on the design team, however, I'd be fighting this limitation.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs from the C# specification: "In addition, because of this rule, the switch sections of a switch statement can be arbitrarily rearranged without affecting the behavior of the statement."

Comment: @phoog: ... glad I added the "but I could be wrong" in there :)  I still think it was the wrong decision though.  Took a graceful code structure and turned it into an unwieldy, unordered thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use goto:

```
        switch (severity.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ALL":
                result.Add("ALL");
                goto case "DEBUG";
            case "DEBUG":
                result.Add("DEBUG");
                goto case "INFO";
            case "INFO":
                result.Add("INFO");
                goto case "WARN";
            case "WARN":
                result.Add("WARN");
                goto case "ERROR";
            case "ERROR":
                result.Add("ERROR");
                goto case "FATAL";
            case "FATAL":
                result.Add("FATAL");
                goto case "OFF";
            case "OFF":
                result.Add("OFF");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Microsoft (implicitly) recommends this use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Yes this would work; it seems silly it would be necessary.  And it may  be aesthetics, but the idea of putting a `goto` clause in my code... not attractive.  :)

Comment: I agree, I think an explicit fallthrough keyword would be ideal, but at least this is an option.

Answer (score 1):

@nemesv's Linq answer is way better solution but if you want to do it with switch you could do like this and will get same result.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SeverityOrHigher(string severity)
{
  var lastFound = -1;

  var severityList = new List<string>() { "ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL", "OFF" };
  var results = new List<string>();

  foreach (var t in severityList)
  {

    if (lastFound > -1)
    {
      for (var index = lastFound + 1; index < severityList.Count; index++)
      {
        results.Add(severityList[index]);
      }
      return results;
    }

    switch (severity.ToUpper())
    {
      case "ALL":
        results.Add(severity);
        lastFound = 0;
        break;
      case "DEBUG":
        lastFound = 1;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
      case "INFO":
        lastFound = 2;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
      case "WARN":
        lastFound = 3;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
      case "ERROR":
        lastFound = 4;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
      case "FATAL":
        lastFound = 5;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
      case "OFF":
        lastFound = 6;
        results.Add(severity);
        break;
    }
  }

  return results;
}
```

**Test:**

```
  var list = SeverityOrHigher("ALL");
  foreach (var severity in list)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(severity);
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not look very nice, but could do the job for you:

```
string s = severity.ToUpper();
result.add("OFF");
if (s == "OFF")
  return result;
result.add("FATAL");
if (s == "FATAL")
  return result;
result.add("ERROR");
if (s == "ERROR")
  return result;
// ...
result.add("ALL");
return result;
```

Comment: bleargh... yeah.  This will work too, but I'm hoping that there's a C# construct for this that isn't so unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with somehting like creating another list which represents all valid severities and checking if the input severity is one of them:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SeverityOrHigher(string severity)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var severities = new List<string> { "ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL", "OFF" };

    severity = severity.ToUpper();

    if (severities.Contain(severity))
            result.Add(severity);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would accomplish what I am trying to do.